# Present Perfect within Present Simple

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect, present-simple

Is it grammatical to use a Present Perfect within a Present Simple, as in:

> This programmer regularly documents any change he has recently made in his code.

?

If the answer is positive, what does the above sentence mean to you? Is it ambiguous and equivocal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatically correct to use this sentence structure. To me the sentence means that frequently the programmer takes notes about recent changes he made in his code.

Comment: Is English your first language?

Comment: Yes, American English is my first language:)